# Mobile website redirection - .htaccess issue

Tags: android, .htaccess, magento

I have a magento website (`justfrompound.com`) and also a mobile website (`justfrompound.com/mobilesite`).  Using .htaccess in root, does redirect to `/mobilesite`, when fetched via an android - but it shows html content - none of the scripting works.

if i remove the following 3 lines from .htaccess - the `/mobilesite` url works perfectly alright.

Can anyone guide as where I am going wrong here?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobilesite/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobilesite/ [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

I applied to only iPhone device so you can apply as per your requirement. you can only bind your device code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-iPhone-site/
RewriteRule .* /my-iPhone-site/ [R]
```